# Changing navigationView header text color

Tags: android, navigationview, android-navigationview

How do you change the header text colors in navigation Drawer. I am using the latest support design library. Image is attached below.

[image: NavigationDrawer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you created it with a separate header xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="178dp"
android:background="@drawable/background_poly"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">



<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="56dp"
     android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Akash Bangad"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="akash.bangad93@gmail.com"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"

        />
</LinearLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/aka"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:id="@+id/circleView"
   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Just Change the background  color of the relative layout

Here is the link I used
       http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html?m=1

Comment: That's for the header. I'm unable to change that menu item headers. "Tv shows" and "Movies"

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem with group title color and I found the solution.
Just put it into style.xml main theme.

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFFFFF</item>
```

No need to modify your parent theme.

Comment: I tried lots of other ways but none of them works. But your solution worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just changing the parent theme from `Theme.Appcombat.Light.ActionBar` to `Theme.AppCombat` solves it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently in the Material Components Library it is based on the **`android:textColorSecondary`** color.

You can override this color only in the `NavigationView` using:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.myCustomTitle"
    ..>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.myCustomTitle" parent="">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

Final result:

[image]