# Set group color NavigationView

Tags: android, xml

Does anyone know how to set the background color of a particular group in a navigationView menu. Im looking for something like this. (obviously this is not working).

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/grp1"
        android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:background="@color/red">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:title="@string/title"  />
    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/grp2"
        android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:background="@color/blue">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/title2"
        android:title="@string/title2"  />
   </group>
</menu>
```

I know i can set the following values on the NavigationView to change the color properties of the whole view

```
 app:itemIconTint
 app:itemTextColor
 app:itemBackground
```

But i want to change color on a per group basis. So far no luck. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I found the answer here: [Tan Jit Ren Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31789668/2036046)