# Changing textcolor of menu item with submenu items in it inside a navigation view

Tags: android, android-layout, menuitem, submenu, android-navigationview

I am having a hard time trying to change the textcolor of menuitems with some sub menuitems in it inside a navigationview. I am able to change the textcolor of the submenu item.

Here's a screenshot of the element that I want to change the color of:

[image: imgur-image]

Here's my menu resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:title="@string/nav_title_1"
        android:id="@+id/title_1">
        <menu>
            <group>
                <item android:title="@string/nav_item_1"
                    android:id="@+id/item_1"/>
                <item android:title="@string/nav_item_2"
                    android:id="@+id/item_2"/>
                <item android:title="@string/nav_item_3"
                    android:id="@+id/item_3"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:title="@string/nav_title_2"
        android:id="@+id/title_2">
        <menu>
            <group>
                <item android:title="@string/nav_item_4"
                    android:id="@+id/item_4"/>
                <item android:title="@string/nav_item_6"
                    android:id="@+id/item_5"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="@string/nav_title_3"
        android:id="@+id/title_3">
        <menu>
            <group>
                <item android:title="@string/nav_item_7"
                    android:id="@+id/item_6"/>
                <item android:title="@string/nav_item_8"
                    android:id="@+id/item_7"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="@string/nav_title_4"
        android:id="@+id/title_4">
        <menu>
            <group android:menuCategory="container">
                <item android:title="@string/nav_item_9"
                      android:id="@+id/item_8"/>
                <item android:title="@string/nav_item_10"
                    android:id="@+id/item_9"/>
                <item android:title="@string/nav_item_11"
                    android:id="@+id/item_10"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>


</menu>
```

Finally the layout resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#CF000000"

        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main">

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing navigationView header text color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277875/changing-navigationview-header-text-color)

Comment: The answer did not help!

Comment: What is primary text color?Post your Color.xml

Comment: Changed the parent theme at styles.xml to Theme.AppCompat. It worked